# Getting exception as commit already called while transaction of fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmenttransaction

Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: commit already called

While fragment transaction getting above exception

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_main, fragment);
       // fragmentTransaction.commit();

        try {
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        }
```

Comment: on which line are you getting it?

Comment: fragmentTransaction.commit();

Comment: are you sure that the `// fragmentTransaction.commit();` line was commented when you got it?

Comment: yes its commented

Comment: Fragment fragment = new TestdriveDetailsFrament(); fragment.setArguments(args); FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment); transaction.addToBackStack(null); try { transaction.commit(); } catch (IllegalStateException e) { transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss(); }

Answer (score -1):

This will help.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();        
transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: how `addToBackStack` should help? Or there is some other difference?

Comment: You can give a try. You will come to know

Comment: you need to explain this for the answer to be treated as good answer. So far it is quite bad.

Comment: Well, If this is not an answer. then let us know the answer that you are expecting

Comment: This is an answer, but the bad one, as I said. You have to explain what is the difference, and how it would help for it to be a good answer.

Comment: How can you say it is bad answer? do let us know

Comment: there is a guide of how to answer here. That's in addition to `transaction.addToBackStack(null);` will not change anything here

Comment: If you dont know the answer. Then just say you dont know. dont say that it is bad answer. And you cant even explain why it is bad answer.

Comment: I don't know the answer because the question is not explained enough, and I try to improve that. I know this answer is bad because it won't work and won't help.

Comment: adding to the backstack has totally nothing to do with `commit already called` exception.

Answer (score -1):

To load fragments use this..

```
Fragment fragment = new MyFragment();
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.frame_layout, fragment).commit();
```

Comment: what is the difference?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko no need to use try/catch